# Rsync compare files in two directories. list only files with difference

Tags: linux, ubuntu, rsync

I am trying to compare files in two directories using rsync.

I am using the command to achieve this is like:

```
rsync -avcn folder1/* folder2/
```

The problem is the result also list all the directories, whereas I want to display on the list of files with difference.

How I can achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `-a` (`--archive`) flag is doing too much in this case; it also wants to make the directory metadata (permissions, timestamps, user, group) equal. Use `-r` instead; then rsync will only list those directories that exist in the `folder1` but not in `folder2`.

If you actually need some of the `-a` behaviour, or you want to ignore directories even if they don't exist in `folder2`, you can filter the output through `grep` because directory names in `rsync`'s output conveniently end with a slash:

```
rsync -avcn folder1/* folder2/ | grep -v '/$'
```